# How do I Create TabMenu on Windows8?

Tags: tabs, microsoft-metro

I want to create Tab on Windows8 like UITabBar on iOS with TopAppBar.
Please tell me !!

Answer (score 0):

There is AppBar in windows 8, what might be alternative to UITabBar. 
[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-AppBar-control-sample-2aa1cbb4) is example

and if you need some design [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770552)

Comment: thx Roma !! I want to set same appbar on some pages.Must I set same appbar on each page ?? I think it is a little redundant.